# Changing desktop background should also change the login picture?

Tags: greeter, settings, desktop

Consider [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/81/170) question on how to change the  login picture.

I cannot in fact follow none of the answers posted there.

But even before re-asking a question like "how to change the login image" I would like to know:

**Should the login use the desktop picture? Should it change when the desktop one is changed and so be the same? Because in my case it is NOT.**

I use to change the **desktop** wallpaper by going to Settings - Desktop - Wallpaper or just right clicking an image 'Set as desktop background' in Files.

My **login** screen is (was) this one no matter what desktop wallpaper I selected:

[image]

That is, until I followed [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/85/170) and now the login image is missing: black.

The folder /usr/share/backgrounds looks like so:

[image]

Notice the added images at the end and the symlink that was created following the linked answer.

But they are not accessible from Settings:

[image]

---

I found a fix to the lost login image:

- Selected one of the default wallpapers that are visible from Settings - Desktop - Wallpaper
- Then changed desktop wallpaper again: in this way the login has an image: **the one before the last change** of the desktop image.

---

### In fact it's a bug. Also, has a workaround: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1324373), also [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1391716).

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: @Tim - Freya, what else...

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1324373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related answer: [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/120/170).

The answer to my question is YES: the login image should also change just by selecting one of the images in `/usr/share/backgrounds` from System Settings -Desktop - Wallpaper.

In fact there is a bug where the login picture cannot be changed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1391716

also:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1324373

In this case the new images copied into `usr/share/backgroounds` may not even be seen from System Settings -Desktop - Wallpaper.

To fix this:

- Open Files as administrator
- Select the image file in `/usr/share/backgrounds` and open its Properties (if you want a new one copy it there first)
- Change permissions to `644`

[image]

- Use System Settings -Desktop - Wallpaper as normal