# Help! : 'This Session is Locked. You'll be directed to the unlock dialog automatically in a few seconds'

Tags: release-freya

I updated Freya using system updates today and all was going well until I walked away from my PC for 20 minutes to make dinner and came back to see a black screen with 'This Session is Locked. You'll be directed to the unlock dialog automatically in a few seconds'  Except that the unlock dialog never appeared not even after ten minutes. I had to shut off the PC and power back up into elementary OS Freya. what is going on?

Comment: Okay i hope i found the solution. System Settings: Security_Privacy then turn off the two buttons there, one being 'Lock on sleep' and the other being 'Lock after screen turns off'.  The software updates must have added this feature because it was not happening prior.  If it ever happens again though, I sure would like to know how to UNlock a locked screen.  Time will tell if my fix fixes this issue. geesh, I wish such an added feature would first pull up a dialog to ask the user if they want the lock feature enabled as it is disconcerting to suddenly see it occur and then power off the PC.

Comment: You are able and encouraged to answer your own question, if you have found a solution to your problem please share it with an answer. Great to know you were able to fix it.